# How to fill spatialite geometry column with values?

Tags: qgis, python, spatialite

This is a follow up to this question: [Export vector layer to sqlite database using pyqgs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242045/export-vector-layer-to-sqlite-database-using-pyqgs)

I am trying to import a QGIS polygon layer into a spatialite db. 
I was able to add a geometry column to my table using

```
cur.execute("SELECT InitSpatialMetadata()")     
cur.execute("SELECT AddGeometryColumn('Polygonx', 'geometry', 4326, 'POLYGON', 'XY')")
```

Subsequently, I am using the following line to insert my values, inlcuding the geometry

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Polygonx VALUES (?,?,?,?)", feature_list)
```

Whereas

```
feature_list = []    
for feature in vlyr.getFeatures():
    attributes = feature.attributes()
    new_feature = (feature.id(), attributes[0], attributes[1], feature.geometry().exportToWkt())
    feature_list.append(new_feature)
```

When using the db manager to check the table, however, the value of the geometry column is always *NULL*. Any idea what wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

(Only a partial answer)

The geometry column in spatialite is not WKT. I think you would need to convert the WKT representiation to a "Geometry BLOB". So either ST_GeomFromText() in your INSERT statement, or the python equivalent.